# How to install NodeJS on RHEL 7.5 server

Tags: node.js, linux, centos, yum, rhel

How to install NodeJS on RHEL server 7.5?

I have root privileges and tried first:

```
curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash -
```

then:

```
yum install -y nodejs
```

Got error:

```
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, product-id, rhui-lb, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.
https://rpm.nodesource.com/pub_8.x/el/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#22 - "The requested URL returned error: 407"
Trying other mirror.
No package nodejs available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

What is recommended way to install NodeJS on RHEL/CentOS servers and how to solve the problem above?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try Edit /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/subscription-manager.conf and set enabled to 0:

enabled=0

Comment: Just tried:   `cat /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/subscription-manager.conf
[main]
enabled=0`   and then tried again YUM:   `yum install -y nodejs
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, product-id, rhui-lb, search-disabled-repos
https://rpm.nodesource.com/pub_8.x/el/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#22 - "The requested URL returned error: 407"
Trying other mirror.
No package nodejs available.
Error: Nothing to do`

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? Error 407 is usually a proxy issue, I'd check your proxy configuration with yum and see if that's an issue. You can do `cat /etc/yum.conf` and see if your proxy information is set there, if not, you can set it by putting the following lines in there:

`proxy=http://<Proxy-Server-IP-Address>:<Proxy_Port>
proxy_username=<Proxy-User-Name>
proxy_password=<Proxy-Password> `

Make sure these are in the `[main]` section.

Comment: There seems to be `http` proxy set in `/etc/yum.conf `. Should I set `https` as well? I could install for example `nano` but not nodejs..

Comment: We can try setting the https one! I'd try `export https_proxy=https://user:password@serverproxy:port` and seeing if that will work.

Comment: Hmm.. tried both `export http_proxy=...` and `export https_proxy=...` but did still the same error..

Comment: @Joe Hi Joe! Did you find a fix to this?